# Pointers in x86 HLA Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, hla

I was wondering if something could explain pointers in Assembly to me.
For example, what would mov( eax, [ebx] );, mov( &iValue, EBX );, and mov( VarName[ eax ], al ); mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Is `iValue` a global variable you declared somewhere?  I'd assume that's equivalent to AT&T syntax `mov $iValue, %EBX`, to put the label address into a register, with a mov-immediate.  For the others, those look like normal Intel-syntax addressing modes for memory operands, see [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101)  (HLA uses `op(src, dst)` order, I think, like AT&T syntax, opposite of the rest of Intel syntax.)

Comment: iValue was just a random variable used in an example that my professor using to explain. Also, thank you!

Comment: Ok, but does HLA not have *local* variables?  In normal asm, you can only `mov` an address as an absolute; to get the address of a local variable (on the stack) into a register, you'd need `lea 4(%esp), %ebx` or whatever.  (Intel `lea ebx, [esp+4]`).  If HLA doesn't try to attach names to stack locations (the way MASM does with `proc` / `local` stuff), then yes, all "variables" are what C would call global or static variables, and would have symbol names just like labels in code.